# solving differential equation $(x+y)=\frac{dy}{dx}(4x+y)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

we've got this differential equation 
$$(x+y)=\frac{dy}{dx}(4x+y)$$
now what should be substituted for $x,y$
i can always do $$x+y=k$$
and then
$$1+\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dk}{dx}$$
but this does't suite here in this case 
$x,y$ in previous problems it was very easy to substitue because cofficients of $x,y$ were same and $x+y=k$ was then substituted now here cofficients are not same so how should i do this??

Comment: Nice approach by the way.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of equation can be written as $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$

where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are homogeneous polynomials in $x$ and $y$ which have the same degree. There is then a standard process which works:

Make the substitution $y=vx$ (where $v$ is a function of $x$) so that $\frac{dy}{dx} = x\frac{dv}{dx}+v$. This reduces the differential equation to one in which the new variables $v, x$ are separable.

If you need further help, I will give a fuller solution.

Comment: this was good enough thanks

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let:

$$y = v x \rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dx} = v + x \dfrac{dv}{dx}$$

Substitute, solve for $v(x)$, substitute back.

Comment: Short and sweet! +1